# Get the correct number of process in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh, ps

I would like to check the number of process that is currently running. The process name is `sol3-script-ui`.

If I run  `ps aux | grep "sol3-script-ui" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l` from the command line directly, then I get 8, which is correct (match with the number when i type "top" from the command line as well).

However, I want to get this number in a bash script and this number will be used as input for some other operations. To simplify, I create a bash script file, `get-sol3-script-ui-nr.sh` and when i run this bash file, it echo 10 on the screen.

What is the cause for the difference in the process number when running in command line and when running in bash script?

How could I get this "8" in the bash script?

```
root@aldo:/home/sol3/script# ps aux | grep "sol3-script-ui" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l
8
root@aldo:/home/sol3/script# ./get-sol3-script-ui-nr.sh 
10
root@aldo:/home/sol3/script# cat get-sol3-script-ui-nr.sh 
#!/bin/bash
sol3Nr=$(ps aux | grep "sol3-script-ui" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l)
echo $sol3Nr
```

Maybe this question is repeated somehow in other post. But it is good someone could explain to me the cause and the solution. I want to get the `sol3Nr` equal to 8, which will be used for other operations.

Comment: Both your script and the `grep` you run within it match what you're looking for.  You can avoid the `grep` matching by using `grep "[s]ol3-script-ui"` — the character class prevent the regex from matching.  You could rename the script to avoid it matching, or you can filter the name out (`grep -v`, again avoiding a match).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I tried the solution `grep "[s]ol3-script-ui`, but somehow it does not work. The answer by Cyrus works for me.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
sol3Nr=$(pgrep sol3-script-ui | wc -l)
```

Comment: If your `pgrep` has the  `-c` flag like in GNU version you can use that instead of `wc`